# Reference for Grassmann and Schubert varieties for Beginners .

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schubert-calculus

I need some references to understand Grassmann and Schubert Variety as a beginner. I am looking for self-contained notes on these. Thanks.

Comment: I liked very much the notes of Jaydeep V. Chipalkatti. They are concise and cover a lot of material but definitely give a good overview and focus on examples or main ideas rather than construct the general theory.  http://:https://server.math.umanitoba.ca/~jaydeep/Site/Papers_files/GrSc.pdf